# C language. How to find the maximum minimum. (2D arrays)

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have written code that allows you to enter one dimension of a NxN double array. It will then print random numbers in a 2D array and it finds the maximum and minimum number of each row. It then prints them and their coordinates (row and column).

ATTENTION!!!!
I have altered my code in such a way that it finds the minimum number of the maximum. I now don't know how to find it's coordinates

My code is as follows:

```
int N, i, j, min=1000, max, m , o;
time_t t;
int masyvas[100][100], minmax[100];
printf("Enter one dimension of a NxN array\n");
scanf("%d", &N);



srand((unsigned) time(&t));
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
        masyvas[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        printf("%4d", masyvas[i][j]);

    }
    printf("\n");
}




int k, l, idkeymax, idkeymin;
for(k=0; k<N; k++)
{

    max=-1000;
    for(l=0; l<N; l++)
    {
        if(max<masyvas[k][l])
        {
            max=masyvas[k][l];

        }

    }
    minmax[k]=max;

}
for(m=0; m<N; m++)
    {if(minmax[m]<min)
        min=minmax[m];
    }

printf("maziausias skaicius tarp didziausiu yra %d eiluteje %d stulpelyje %d\n",min);
```

Comment: unrelated, but you should check the `N` the user enters is in the range [1,10]. Otherwise, you'll go out-of-bounds of your array (`N==0` would be fine too but nothing would happen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the pseudo code of what you need to do.

```
for row in grid {
    row_max = max_in_row(row)
    grid_min = min(grid_min, row_max)
}
```

Step one is to write a routine that finds the max and location in a list. You could do this as one big function, but it's much easier to understand and debug in pieces.

You also need the index where it was found. Since C can't return multiple values, we'll need a struct to store the number/index pair. Any time you make a struct, make routines to create and destroy it. It might seem like overkill for something as trivial as this, but it will make your code much easier to understand and debug.

```
typedef struct {
    int num;
    size_t idx;
} Int_Location_t;

static Int_Location_t* Int_Location_new() {
    return calloc(1, sizeof(Int_Location_t));
}

static void Int_Location_destroy( Int_Location_t* loc ) {
    free(loc);
}
```

Now we can make a little function that finds the max number and position in a row.

```
static Int_Location_t* max_in_row(int *row, size_t num_rows) {
    Int_Location_t *loc = Int_Location_new();

    /* Start with the first element as the max */
    loc->num = row[0];
    loc->idx = 0;

    /* Compare starting with the second element */
    for( size_t i = 1; i < num_rows; i++ ) {
        if( row[i] > loc->num ) {
            loc->num = row[i];
            loc->idx = i;
        }
    }

    return loc;
}
```

Rather than starting with some arbitrary max or min, I've used an alternative technique where I set the max to be the first element and then start checking from the second one.

---

Now that I have a function to find the max in a row, I can now loop over it, get the max of each row, and compare it with the minimum for the whole table.

```
int main() {
    int grid[3][3] = {
        {10, 12, 15},
        {-50, -15, -10},
        {1,2,3}
    };

    int min = INT_MAX;
    size_t row = 0;
    size_t col = 0;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        Int_Location_t *max = max_in_row(grid[i], 3);
        printf("max for row %zu is %d at %zu\n", i, max->num, max->idx);

        if( max->num < min ) {
            min = max->num;
            col = max->idx;
            row = i;
        }

        Int_Location_destroy(max);
    }

    printf("min for the grid is %d at row %zu, col %zu\n", min, row, col);
}
```

I used a different technique for initializing the minimum location, because getting the first maximum would require repeating some code in the loop. Instead I set `min` to the lowest possible integer, `INT_MAX` from [limits.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) which is highest possible integers. This allows the code to be used with any range of integers, there are no restrictions. This is a very common technique when working with min/max algorithms.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But this excersise requires me not to use struct. I have altered the code in such a way that it finds the min number. Now I've got the trouble of finding it's coordinates. I understand that you're coding in an efficient way. But this is a fairly simple task where I can only use arrays and nothing more, maybe functions for my preference, but the simplicity is what makes this hard to think of. Do you have any ideas how could I store the coordinates so I could print them, from this code :

Comment: @Rytis \*sigh\* Silly homework restrictions, they teach bad habits. You can sidestep the struct restriction by using a two element integer array; first is the number, second is the location. Use `#define NUM 0` and `#define IDX 1` so you can write `max[NUM]` and `max[IDX]` for readability. This allows you to continue to use functions rather than cram everything into a multi-level loop.

Comment: Silly question, but how do I add code to my comment, I think it would be easier for you to see what I've done, rather than mumble about. And I do agree with you, restrictions are not good for being efficient. :x

Comment: @Rytis Backticks are for code, but only single lines. You're better off editing your question with the extra detail, there's an edit button, then everyone can see it.

Comment: Will do, just a heads up, some of the words will be Lithuanian as am I, so if someone will not understand I will translate everything. Just a sec.

Comment: @Rytis My answer is the same. You need to store the index of the min/max along with the min/max itself. You can use a struct, or you can use an array of two elements. You've done it as two separate loops passing a list of the row maxes between them, I've done it as an inner (`max_in_row` is the inner loop) and outer loop to avoid needing an intermediate list, but both need a way to pair the min/max with its index. `max[NUM] = masyvas[k][l]; max[IDX] = l;`